# DynamicRows - underscore's function last() is not defined

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, uicomponent

After A LOT of struggling with Dynamic Rows, I finally have something.

1) I created DataProvider Modifier to add my data into form initial data.

2) I have the "legendary code" in my XML file that finally works:

```
<dynamicRows name="slides">
            <settings>
                <identificationProperty>slide_id</identificationProperty>
                <addButtonLabel translate="true">Add Swatch</addButtonLabel>
                <additionalClasses>
                    <class name="admin__field-wide">true</class>
                </additionalClasses>
                <componentType>dynamicRows</componentType>
                <columnsHeader>false</columnsHeader>
                <addButton>false</addButton>
            </settings>
            <container name="record" component="Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                        <item name="positionProvider" xsi:type="string">position</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <field name="slide_id">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Slider ID</item>
                            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">slide_id</item>
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">slide_id</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </field>
                <field name="position" component="Magento_Catalog/js/form/element/input" formElement="input">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="prefixName" xsi:type="string">slide.position</item>
                            <item name="prefixElementName" xsi:type="string">slide_</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                    <settings>
                        <additionalClasses>
                            <class name="_hidden">true</class>
                        </additionalClasses>
                        <dataType>text</dataType>
                        <visible>false</visible>
                        <dataScope>position</dataScope>
                    </settings>
                </field>
            </container>
        </dynamicRows>
```

But there's a problem:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.parentName.split(...).last is not a function in (...)/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Catalog/js/form/element/input.js:40
```

function last() seems to be from underscore and I can see it defined in top of the file:

```
    define([
        'underscore',
        'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract'
    ], function (_, Acstract) {
        'use strict';
(...)
```

That part of code:

```
this.parentName.split('.')
```

Is returning nice array.

I know that I'm super-close to achieve my goal:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know how to eliminate the problem, try to eliminate the code.

Change:

```
                <field name="position" component="Magento_Catalog/js/form/element/input" formElement="input">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="prefixName" xsi:type="string">slide.position</item>
                            <item name="prefixElementName" xsi:type="string">slide_</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                    <settings>
                        <additionalClasses>
                            <class name="_hidden">true</class>
                        </additionalClasses>
                        <dataType>text</dataType>
                        <visible>false</visible>
                        <dataScope>position</dataScope>
                    </settings>
                </field>
```

To:

```
        <field name="position">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="prefixName" xsi:type="string">slide.position</item>
                    <item name="prefixElementName" xsi:type="string">slide_</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <additionalClasses>
                    <class name="_hidden">true</class>
                </additionalClasses>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <visible>false</visible>
                <dataScope>position</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
```

As you can see, I removed the `component` attribute, so it no longer use it. I moved `formElement`, but just for clarity.

I hope it will help someone to do it faster then me - there is defintelly lack of documentation for UI Components in M2 and there is no working example on stackoverflow or stackexchange how to implement dynamicRows too.